# How do I get the return value from a scalar stored procedure in ASP C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and I want it to return a sum of a column of values.  When I use the `SqlCommand`, I add the parameter `enrollmentId`.  When I try to run my code in Visual Studio, it says I have to provide the parameter `@totalEarned`... my problem is that is what I am using the SP to determine... it is supposed to output `@totalEarned`. How do I use this SP without providing `@totalEarned`?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[totalEarned]
    @enrollmentId Int,
    @totalEarned int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @totalEarned = SUM(pointsEarned)
    FROM Assignments
    WHERE enrollmentId = @enrollmentId

    RETURN
END
```

Here's the C# code:

```
string connstring;
connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.totalEarned", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@enrollmentId", enrollmentId));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totalEarned", null));
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();

    double totalEarned = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using OUTPUT, change your return to `return @totalEarned`

Comment: yeah I realized that but it's still giving me the same message.

Comment: Also remove it from the SP parameters.  You don't need it @totalEarned at all in the SQL, but you can have it as a DECLARE if it makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to specify `Direction`. Replace `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totalEarned", null));` with:

```
SqlParameter totalEarned= new SqlParameter("@totalEarned", SqlDbType.Int);
totalEarned.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(totalEarned);
```

Then after executing command, cast it to `int` to get the value:

```
int value = (int)totalEarned.Value;
```

Comment: it's saying ParameterDirection doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: use fully qualified name: `System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: Now it's saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. referring to the int value = (int)totalEarned.Value;

Comment: Use `int result=cmd.Parameters["@totalEarned"].Value` and see if you get the correct result

Answer (score 1):

When you construct the `SqlParameter` set its `Direction` property to `Output`.

Alternatively, simply `SELECT SUM(pointsEarned)` directly.